# Vectorizing a df.apply() Operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a (493,20) pandas dataframe and want to compute a conditional np.nanmean() for each row. The condition is that each value in the row needs to be above a certain threshold and below another. Here's my current setup:

```
filt_avg_data= np.nanmean(data_tsl.apply(func= lambda x: x[(x < maxval*np.median(x)) & (x > minval*np.median(x))], axis= 1),axis=1)
```

where maxval: 10, minval: 0.1, and data_tsl.shape= (493,20). This works okay.

However, I want to vectorize this operation - I don't want to use the *df.apply()* function. I tried

`data_tsl>np.median(data_tsl,axis=1)`
 to create a mask of values on which I can perform a np.nanmean() operation on, but it seems as though I can't get each row of `data_tsl` to correspond to its respective median value. Here is the error that pops up: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (493,2) (493,)`

How might I be able to vectorize this operation? Several questions that were similar to this weren't actually asking to vectorize the problem - rather, simply to get the .apply() operation to work.

Comment: Wouldn't you use `np.nanmedian` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `NaNs` in the input data, I would think you want to use `np.nanmedian` to ignore `NaNs` from the median calculation. Going with it, we can use the combined mask for the upper and lower thresholds to set the invalid ones to `NaNs` as well and finally use `np.nanmean` -

```
a = data_tsl.values # use data_tsl.values.copy() to avoid editing input df
med = np.nanmedian(a,axis=1)
U = maxval*med
L = minval*med

a[(a >= U[:,None]) | (a <= L[:,None])] = np.nan
out = np.nanmean(a,axis=1)
```

Comment: I don't need to use np.nanmedian() since I don't have NaNs in my input data. The np.nanmean() is necessary because the masking (via np.median()) returns the data array with NaN values for elements that didn't match the condition.

Comment: Awesome! This works. Can you give some intuition as to why the Nones are necessary, despite U and L being 1D? The point seems subtle but obviously important, since the solution doesn't work otherwise (the Nones also work if I used them in my original attempt).